# File Upload Error in Classic ASP

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, image-uploading, object-persistence, photo-upload

```vbs
Set PersistsUpload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload.1")
PersistsUpload.Save 
set persistsfile = PersistsUpload.Files("file")
```

When I am uploading the file the following error is returned:

```
Request.BinaryRead failed: Unspecified error
```

Comment: There's actually very little information here: what type of file are you uploading, how big is the file, does the user have access to the file (OS), etc.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it means that your upload script uses Request.Form or Request.QueryString prior to calling Upload.Save  XXX. As a result, the BinaryRead method of the Request object fails.

see:
http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS01032216